# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ums.people' doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am building a simple registration and login system. I have created the forms and the database. My database name is "ums" and the table name is "persons". Whenever I click the registration button it says, SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ums.people' doesn't exist. I want to insert data into "persons" table. Where did it find the people table?
Here is my Controller code:

```
function regSubmit(Request $req)
    {
        @$this->validate($req,
                        [
                            "name"=>"required|max:20|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+(([',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/",
                            "email"=>"required|regex:/^([1-9]{2}-[0-9]{5}-[1-3]{1})\@student\.aiub\.edu+$/",
                            "password"=>"required|min:8|regex:/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$/",
                            "conf_password"=>"required|same:password",
                            "type"=>"required"
                
                        ],
                        [
                            "name.required"=> "Please Enter Your Name",
                            "name.max"=> "Maximum 20 Characters",
                            "name.regex"=>"Please Enter A Valid Name",
                            "email.required"=>"Please Enter Your Email Address",
                            "email.regex"=>"Please Enter A Valid Email Address",
                            "password.required"=>"Please Enter A Password",
                            "password.min"=>"Minimum 8 Characters",
                            "password.regex"=>"password must contain a special character, a number and an uppercase letter",
                            "conf_password.required"=>"Please Confirm Your Password",
                            "conf_password.same"=>"Password do not match",
                            "type.required"=>"Please Enter User Type"
                        ]
                        );
                        
                        $p1 = new Person();
                        $p1->name = $req->name;
                        $p1->email = $req->email;
                        $p1->password = $req->password;
                        $p1->type = $req->type;
                        $p1->save();
                        return redirect('users.login');
    }
```

Here is the HTML Form:

```
@extends('layouts.logoutlay')
@section('content')
<form action ="{{route('users.reg.submit')}}" method="post" style="margin: auto; width: 220px;">
{{@csrf_field()}}
Name: <input type = "text" value = "{{old('name')}}" name ="name"></br>
@error('name')
        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span><br>
@enderror
Email: <input type = "text" value = "{{old('email')}}" name ="email"></br>
@error('email')
        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span><br>
@enderror
Password: <input type="password" value = "{{old('password')}}" name="password"></br>
@error('password')
        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span><br>
@enderror
Confirm Password : <input type="password" value = "{{old('conf_password')}}" name="conf_password"></br>
@error('conf_password')
        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span><br>
@enderror
Type : <input type="radio" value="user" name="type"> User  <input type="radio" value="admin" name="type"> Admin  </br>
@error('type')
        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span><br>
@enderror
   

</br>


<input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel Eloquent follows a convention of naming tables for the model class - it's generally the snake_case plural of the model class name in lower case.

So in this case the model is called **Person** and eloquent will try to find a table named **people** for the model. If you have the table as **persons** for the model **Person** you will need to ensure that table name is specified on the model class

```php
class Person extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'persons';

   // Rest of the model class code
}
```

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent - Table Names](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#table-names)

Comment: Where do I write this line?

Comment: @MehediHasanTalha You will need to add this in the model class **Person.php**. Just have a look at the documentation link

Comment: It is now saying SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'assignment.persons' doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you run the migrations? What's the database config in your `.env` file and `config/database.php` files?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The table name was "person". I changed it "persons". I forgot to pluralize.